# Only load managed assembly DLLs in directory

Tags: .net, asp.net

I need to load all the assemblies from DLLs in a directory.

My basic code is:

```
var assemblies = from filename in Directory.GetFiles(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "*.dll")
                 select Assembly.LoadFrom(filename);
```

However, if there are unmanaged DLLs in that directory then Assembly.LoadFrom fails. Is there a good way to only load the managed DLLs? Catching the load exception is an option, but I'd like to know if there's a better way.

My code runs on ASP.NET, at application start up. So I'll also accept an ASP.NET specific solution.

Comment: Do you have to use bin? Could you load from another directory that contains only managed dll's?

Comment: Yes it has to be the asp.net 'bin' directory for this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/02/06/68334.aspx

"Assembly.LoadFrom will throw BadImageFormatException if the given file is not a managed assembly.

This exception could be thrown for other reason as well. Suzanne kindly points out a more robust way. Once you catch the BadImageFormatException, look at its HResult field. If HResult is COR_E_ASSEMBLYEXPECTED, it means this is not a managed assembly."

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, that'll at least mean I can be very exact about when to ignore the load exception. Basically I want to avoid swallowing load exceptions that occur for any another reason.

Answer (score 5):

Just loop through them separately and put the `Assembly.LoadFrom` in a `try...catch` block.

Answer (score 3):

Some googling led me to this page: [Detect if an assembly is a managed assembly](http://koen.williame.be/blog/post/Detect-if-an-assembly-is-a-managed-assembly.aspx) . Sounds like this would be a great fit.

It really depends how many unmanaged dlls you expect and how sensitive you are about your startup time (I am assuming you're doing this on startup). If you can relax on both accounts, the `try...catch` surely is the simplest thing to do, otherwise, reading the assembly header information should be orders of magnitude quicker.

Comment: Very cool! But I'm going to go with catching the BadImageFormatException and checking the HResult since I don't expect unmanaged DLLs to be there most of the time :)

Answer (score 1):

Call [`GetAssemblyName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173100.aspx) and if it throws a BadImageFormatException, then it's not a Assembly.